# Ionic Framework: GridLayout with multiple rows and column on which buttons placed for an arrayItem

Tags: ionic-framework

On a page, using ng-repeat, I try to place buttons on a grid layout. 
Iterating through an array which is defined in a controller $scope.btnNames[]. buttons are place on  Total number of buttons equal to array size of  $scope.btnNames[]

I would like to put say 4 buttons per row.
As $scope.btnNames[] size is 20, then I like to place 20 buttons on 5 rows, 
where each row will have 4  buttons.

1) on Controller :
- I have an array with button names 
   $scope.btnNames['aa', 'bb', 'cc','dd', 'ee', 'ff'....] whose size is 20.

2) on the page:
- using ng-repeat, iterate throught the
   $scope.btnNames[] and put buttons as per follwoing code

```
<body ng-controller="PopupCtrl">
 <div class="row responsive-sm"> 
    <div ng-repeat="btnName in btnNames"> 
       <button id={{$index}} class="button button-dark col" >{{btnName}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me defining class="row" and class="col" and such a way that,
during ng-repate, after 4th button, it should add a new row and place 4 buttons till it reach end of ng-repeat.

Being new to both ionic and angulrJs, I'm not able to define class="row" during ng-repeat ( similar like a for loop, where, put a new class="row", when iterator counter in this case {{index}} greater than 4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find a possible solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23780288/1015046

I have taken the above solution and implemented it for Ionic : http://codepen.io/arvindr21/pen/EaVLRN

```
<div ng-repeat="btnName in btnNames">
   <div ng-if="$index%4==0" class="row">
      <div class="col">
         <button id={{$index}} class="button button-dark">{{btnNames[$index]}}</button>
         <button id={{$index+1}} class="button button-dark">{{btnNames[$index+1]}}</button>
         <button id={{$index+2}} class="button button-dark">{{btnNames[$index+2]}}</button>
         <button id={{$index+3}} class="button button-dark">{{btnNames[$index+3]}}</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you want the grid to be dynamic, you can take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27080632/1015046

Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

## Use `flex-wrap`

You can get this behavior by using `style="flex-wrap: wrap;"` + the following CSS classes:

```
<div class="row" style="flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <div class="col col-25" ng-repeat="btnName in btnNames"> 
        <button class="button button-dark" >{{btnName}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### http://codepen.io/Jossef/pen/doeJJP

Comment: I would suggest that this answer becomes the suggested answer, since it is way more elegant. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, So if you want to stack images like me in rows, See how the ng-repeat holds col-50.

```
<div class="row gallery">
    <div class="col col-50" ng-repeat="photo in photos">
           <img  id="fitWidth" ng-src="{{photo.url}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then with your css.

```
.gallery {
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Tested on IOS, Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I would just like to add to the @Jossef Harush's answer (which, btw, worked).

However, when I tested it in the Ionic View application on **iPhone**, it didn't work. When I tested it in the Ionic View application on **Android** it worked as expected (multiple rows).

The solution was to add this as a style:

```
style="display: -webkit-flex; -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;"
```

because, as you can [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-wrap.asp) Safari needs a `-webkit` prefix.

Hope this helps someone who will choose this solution over @Arvind's.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me as soon as I added `flex-wrap: wrap` in the styling.
Since i have set `col-50` I started getting rows with two columns as intended.

Example:

```
<div class="row" style="flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <div class="col col-50" ng-repeat="picture in pictures">
        {{picture.src}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a `limitTo` starting `$index` in AngularJS, 
Maybe that can simplify things

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="element in elements" ng-if="$index % 4==0">
    <div class="element" ng-repeat="element in elements|limitTo:4:$index">...</div>
</div>
```

That will make sure that `{{ index + 1 }}` fall on a non-existent cell ..