# FileTransfer is not defined - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm currently trying to make a CSV file downloadable on the mobile device of the user. I'm using the cordova library.

I've an error who occur when I try to launch the function which download the file.

My Function in my controller

```
  $scope.downloadFilefunction = function () {

      console.log("started");

      var source = $scope.downloadCSV();
      var fileName = source.split("/").pop();
      var filePath = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/';
      console.log("filepath :::");
      var options = {};
      $cordovaFileTransfer.download(source, filePath, options, true).then(
          function (result) {
              console.log("success", JSON.stringify(result));
          }, function (err) {
              console.log("error", JSON.stringify(err));
          });
  }
```

I've added CordovaFileTransfer and cordovaFile in dependencies, I've already try to remove android and add it again after. 
Let me know if you need more information

My index.html :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src='lib/signature_pad/signature_pad.js'></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
      <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/ng-csv/build/ng-csv.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js\require.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my view :

```
<ion-view view-title="Pluri EDL - EDL logement simple">

    <ion-content>

        <div class="home-hello">
            <img src="img\interior_1.jpg" style ="height : 300px;"/>
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                <h1>Etat des lieux </h1>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!--
         | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239735/ionic-framwork-gridlayout-with-multiple-rows-and-column-on-which-buttons-placed
         | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779773/angularjs-loops-and-formatting/23780288#23780288
         -->

     <ion-slide-box>

             <ion-slide> </br>
                <h3 style="text-align:center;"> Informations </h3>
                <label class="item item-input">
               <span class="input-label">Nom et prénom du castmember</span>
               <input type="text" ng-model="informationsresidents.nom">
             </label>

 <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Numéro de chambre</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="informationsresidents.chambre">
</label>

<label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label">ID Castmember</span>
<input ng-model="informationsresidents.id" type="text"></input>
</label>



</ion-slide>




       <ion-slide ng-repeat="categorie in categories" style="padding : 10px;">
                <h3 style="text-align:center;"> {{categorie.name}} </h3>
 <label ng-repeat="critere in categorie.criteres">{{critere.name}}<br />
     <div ng-repeat="etat in etats">
         <ion-radio name="{{critere.name}}" ng-model="critere.etat" ng-value="etat.text"> {{ etat.text }} </ion-radio>
    </div>
 </br>
 </label>
</ion-slide>


<ion-slide>
</br>
    <canvas ng-controller="SignatureCtrl" id='signatureCanvas' min-width='300px'  height='180' style='border: 1px solid black;'></canvas>
    <div class='button-bar'>
            <a class='button button-energized' ng-click='clearCanvas()'>Clear</a>
            <a class='button button-balanced' ng-click='saveCanvas()'>Save</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <img ng-src='{{signature}}'/>

    <ion-item>
    <a href = "#/app/signature"><p>
        <button href="#/app/signature">SAUVEGARDER ET ENVOYER</button>
    </p> </a>
    <button ng-click="sendEmail()" class="button button-icon icon ion-email">
Send mail
</button>
<button ng-click="downloadFile()" class="button button-icon icon ion-email">
Send mail 2
</button>
    </ion-item>



</ion-slide>


<ion-slide style="padding : 10px;">
     <h3 style="text-align:center;">Generer rapport</h3>
      <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="saveJSON()" ng-href="{{ url }}">Enregistrer les informations de l'état des lieux</button>
            <button ng-csv="exemple_json" csv-header="getHeader()" field-separator=" {{separator}} "  filename="{{filename}}">Export</button>
            <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="downloadFilefunction()">Enregistrer les informations de l'état des lieux 3 </button>

</br> </br>
        <a href = "#/app/signature">
            <p>
                <button href="#/app/signature">Passer à la signature electronique </button>
            </p>
        </a>
</ion-slide>
<ion-slide>

    <div>
    <h2>Exemple JSON</h2>

    {{exemple_json | json}}
  </div>

  <br />
  <hr>

  <div>
    <h2>Exemple CSV</h2>

 <button ng-csv="exemple_json" csv-header="getHeader()" field-separator=" {{separator}} "  filename="{{filename}}">Export</button>
  </div>

</ion-slide>

</ion-slide-box>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Someone know how could I avoid this error, or at least making able the download of the file. Thanks you by advance.

Comment: Could you post your HTML code? Have you included cordova.js file in your html? Registered deviceready event?

Comment: Of course I can, I did it, thanks. 
About the deviceready event could you say me more ? I've seen some things about it but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you need to make an entry in your index.html for ngCordova  I guess..

Comment: What do you mean I believed these two lines was the call for cordova library : 
 <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>  

Do you think I should add another call ?

Comment: @ArnaudHMZ I guess any one is good enough. you need not have to include both. i guess you are ionic framework, so ensure to call plugin code inside plaform ready function which should be available in app.js in barebone ionic project